# How to tell routes.php to NOT to use a controller if a certain string is in the url in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

So, I'm struggeling with this problem.
I got these two types of URLS:

***localhost/en/women***

***localhost/en/women/products***

And I'm trying to tell CodeIgniter to use route X if its **localhost/en/women** but use route Y if its **localhost/en/women/products**, but It always uses the X route instead.

I tried to exclude the /products segment by using regex like this:

```
$route['^en/women(?!products)(.*)'] = "women";

$route['^en/women/products'] = "products";
```

But I can't seem to get it to work.

I hope you get what I'm looking for here.
Any feedback is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['en/women/?'] = "women";
$route['en/women/products'] = "products";
```

Should solve this?

Basicly `^` and `$` exist in the regexp by default.

Or maybe you need a:

```
$route['^en/women/products'] = "products";
$route['^en/women/?'] = "women";
```

Just have the `products` above, and it should override.

Answer (score 0):

Use CI's WildCards!

```
$route['en/women'] = "women";
$route['en/women/(:any)'] = "products";
```